# How do I get my php file to read these images correctly?

Tags: php, image

I've created this to get the size of several images I have in a directory....

```
$image = file_get_contents("$fileLocation");
$source = imagecreatefromstring($image);

$width = imagesx($source);
$height = imagesy($source);
echo " &nbsp; width : ", $width, " $nbsp; height : ", $height,
```

When it gets to an image with a name that has a space in the name, it gives me an error....

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format
>   in /setupdb.php on line 23
>
> Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in /setupdb.php on line 25
>
> Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in /setupdb.php on line 26

What do I need to add to get it to read them better?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not about spaces in the filename but about unrecognized image formats. Filenames with spaces for supported image formats will work without errors or warnings (**Except you are not reading them correctly and complete into the variable `$fileLocation` but that part is missing in your code!**).
You can check the supported image formats of your php installation by running `var_dump(gd_info());`.

I would suggest to change your code like this to identify all the files that are not supported images in your directory:

```
$image = file_get_contents("$fileLocation");
$source = imagecreatefromstring($image);

if ($source){
    $width = imagesx($source);
    $height = imagesy($source);
    echo "width : " . $width . " height : ". $height;
} else {
    echo $fileLocation . " is not a recognized image format";
}
```

Comment: Once I added 
str_replace(" ", '%20', $images[$x]); 
it worked.

Comment: Nice, but what is `$images[$x]`? That part of the code is not in your question :-). So the assumption that you are not reading your files correctly into `$fileLocation` seems to be right. Anyway, you solved your problem and that's good for you.

Comment: Sorry, I put all of the image locations in an array and the $x is just a counter. I'm done with this part of my program. I'm stuck on another part.

Thanks